# Coordinates of a vector with respect to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Find (if there exists) a $γ ∈ R^3$, such that the system $(1, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0), γ$ constitutes
a basis of the space $R^3$
and the coordinates of the vector $(7, 3, 5)$ are $3$, $1$, $2$ in the
basis.

Comment: There exists such a vector because the first two vectors are not multiples.

Answer (score 2):

You basically want to find $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that
\begin{align}
3\cdot (1, 0, 1) + 1\cdot (2, 1, 0)+2\cdot(\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3) = (7, 3, 5). 
\end{align}
Just compute to solve for $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$.

Comment: oh really? only this? thank you:)